# Cant stop playing sound in other Activity with MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to play a background sound in my Android application. I'm using a seperate class as   a Soundmanager. And in my first activity, i start the sound and i want it to play through 2 other activitys. And in my third class i want it to stop and another sound should play.
But im having a problem stopping that sound and don't know why. I guess it has something to do with that im using the class Context in my Soundmanager class.

Does anyone know how to make the sound stop? I'll link my Soundmanager class becuase that is the only one that is relevant i guess. Im pretty new to programming, so please be gentle.

Soundmanager class
http://codepad.org/KJi6DZN6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all of your methods and class variables in `SoundManager` static (and pass in a `Context` for the methods that require one).

I would suspect that you are maybe creating a new instance of `SoundManager` in each of your Activities, which would create multiple instances of `SoundManager`. Making it statically accessible will mean all Activities are modifying the same variables.

Another note, I don't think you have to have an Activity `Context`, so try passing in your application's Context via `context.getApplicationContext()`. This will avoid tying the `MediaPlayer` object to any specific Activity.

Comment: That worked great with static! Thank you! but i did not get context.getApplicationContext() to work, but i'll try to read more about it.

Comment: Great to hear. It's quite possible it only works with an Activity's `Context`. Was worth trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as I don't know how you are sharing your Soundmanager object:

Maybe you create a new instance of your Soundmanager class in every Activity that is supposed to use it. (i.e. there is a `new Soundmanager(context)` in each of them or at least an additional one in the stopping Activity).

Comment: Yes, in every Activity im using SoundManager i have SoundManager sm = new SoundManager(this);
And in my first activity i'm calling the method sm.loopSound();
and i want it to stop in my third activity using sm.stopSound() and sm.release(); but it doesn't work.